# How to save link into variable using selenium python 3?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, save, bots

Currently making a Instagram bot using selenium on python-3 so far it logs onto Instagram then goes to my saved content then clicks on first image. It is on the first image on saved and it clicks on the 3 dot button Instagram notifies me that the link is saved onto clipboard. Is it possible to save what I have on clipboard to a variable?

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(imagelink).click()
sleep(3)

print(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the module `pyperclip`

Install pyperclip using pip:-

```
pip install pyperclip
```

And then you can store it in a variable:

```py
import pyperclip

copiedtext = pyperclip.paste() #Your copied link is now stored in this variable

print(copiedtext)
```